# The Selenium application properties folder holds two environment options. After running a test the environment setting changes to a previous setting

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, caching, properties

In the Selenium application properties folder, we have given the environment two options to select from but after running a test and switching from one to the other the test is showing a bias for one particular env setting instead. One I didn't select.

Any ideas as to why this would occur? And how to fix it?

Areas I checked: I verified the properties folder after the test and it shows that it was reverted to the same one. I used the Invalidate Cache restart method with no success. Closing the project also didn't work either.

Comment: you should probably include some code, and if you are using a specific framework, include the name of the framework you are using.

Comment: # environment to enter - qa, staging
env=qa

Comment: Has to be a configuration or update issue  - I seem to be the only one with the issue though as we share the same information - at least most of it